# A BibTeX-like package for images?

Tags: graphics, bibtex, database

Is there something akin to BibTeX that can be used for images? It would be helpful to have an image database, wherein static information like image source and date could be kept and referenced.

Comment: You can add a field to your BibTeX file referring to your image files. Compiling the images together into a single huge PDF file is possible if you edit your BibTeX style file adding `\includegraphics` with your field as an argument.

Comment: But I’m not sure at all TeX is the best solution for your needs. There are plenty of programs for [managing image collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_organizer), taking advantage of [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) matadata.

Comment: @júda-ronén, thanks for your comments. Can you expand a little on your first suggestion (`\includegraphics` in a style file)?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a hack that works. I'm using biblatex. In a .bib file there is this entry:

```
@Misc{crete,
addendum                 = {Bull-leaping in Crete.},
annotation               = {Bull-leaping in Crete. Photo by Wolfgang Sauber, Wikimedia Commons.}
}
```

The image file is named `crete.jpg`. I created a `\Figura` command with this definition:

```
\newcommand{\Figura}[1]{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}
\caption[\citefield{#1}{annotation}]{\citefield{#1}{addendum}}
}
```

`\citefield` is a biblatex command. In the main file, I used the `\Figura` command like this:

```
\begin{figure}
   \Figura{crete}
   \label{fig:crete}
\end{figure}
```

The content of the addendum field is the figure caption, the content of the annotation field is the caption as it appears at the figure list. The image source is included in the annotation field.

Since I used the filename as the biblatex key, I can use the filename directly as the parameter for `\Figura`. I don't know if it would be possible to have the filename in `\includegraphics` as a dynamic field, or in the `\label` command, but I suspect that it wouldn't work.